# Сайт не отдает данные на python

Tags: python, веб-скрейпинг

подскажите пожалуйста, что следует изучить и какое видео стоит посмотреть по данной проблеме. Есть код, с помощью которого я сначала авторизуюсь на сайте, далее я хочу взять информацию  о предстоящих заданиях, нажав на просмотр кода, я нахожу данную информацию, только когда собираюсь ее забрать, мне сайт ее не отдает. Что делать в данной ситуации?

```
user_info = passwrd
    login = user_info[0]
    password = user_info[1]
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'
        user = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': user.random
        }

        response = session.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        login_token = soup.find('input', {'name': "logintoken"})['value']

        data = {
            "logintoken": login_token,
            "username": login,
            "password": password
        }
        response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)

        profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/my/'
        profile_response = session.get(profile_info, headers=headers)
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response.text, 'lxml')
        infa = soup1.select_one('.action-menu-trigger')
        infa1 = infa.select_one('.usertext.mr-1').text
        prdedstoiashee = soup1.select_one('.text-xs-center.text-center.mt-3').text.strip()
        return f"{infa1}\n{prdedstoiashee}"
    except AttributeError:
        return 'Логин или пароль введен неверно.'
```

Comment: Если вы видите информацию в браузере, а requests не видит её, то возможно она подгружается после загрузки страницы. В таком случае возможно можно найти где она подгружается во вкладке Network (Chrome) либо использовать что-то вроде `selenium`.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже почти полностью перешел на мысль с selenium, но все же хотелось бы разобраться с requests